# Not able to connect Salesforce with marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am trying to connect Salesforce with Marketing cloud but I am getting below exception so I am not able to connect.

**An exception occurred while saving the integration.**

[image]

Comment: As the error doesn't display many details of the issue, I would suggest reviewing the steps of how to configure the Marketing Cloud Connector and, in case the issue persists, open a case to support.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Salesforce support is useless.

Comment: I have changed the salesforce org and start from scratch that time it was working

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try

1. Try doing this in Incognito/Private Browser mode. Only log in to Marketing Cloud and then when prompted login to Salesforce
2. Try clearing out tokens that might be left behind, if you had previously connected this Salesforce instance, and then retry connecting. You can find the steps [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000336685&type=1) with the following code in the Execute Anonymous window

```
list<User> userlist = [SELECT ID, Name FROM User WHERE et4ae5__ExactTargetForAppExchangeUser__c = TRUE]; 
for (User i : userlist){ 
try { 
string toDelete = i.id; 
et4ae5.supportutilities.deleteusertokens(toDelete, TRUE); 
} 
catch (Exception e) { 
system.debug('Current user ='+i.Name+' Parent Record.'); 
} 
} 
et4ae5__Configuration__c[] curconfig = [SELECT ID FROM et4ae5__Configuration__c]; 
try { 
delete curconfig; 
} 
catch (Exception e) { 
system.debug('Error Config'); 
} 
try { 
et4ae5.supportutilities.deleteusertokens('APIUSER'); 
} 
Catch (Exception e) { 
system.debug('API Error'); 
}
```

If neither of this works you could reach out to support.

Answer (score 0):

I request you to please verify if you have correctly configured the connected app permission to the system user using steps given in below document- or find the attached document give this permission under connected app [image]

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_upgrade_to_connected_app_authentication.htm&type=5